# How to find first link within @object.each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to find the first link_to 'Comprar' within this @object.each method with Capybara without falling in the ambiguity error, I've tried
`first('a', text:'Comprar').click`
and
`find('a', text:'Comprar').click`
but I'm still having trouble to find the best way to do it work with the options given in the Capybara wiki

```
<% @plans.each do |plan| %>
<dl>
  <dt>Plataforma: </dt>
  <dd><%= plan.platform %></dd>
  <dt>Preço: </dt>
  <dd><%= plan.price %></dd>
  <dt>Promoção: </dt>
  <dd><%= plan.promo %></dd>
  <%= link_to 'Comprar', orders_path(plan),method: :create %>
</dl>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do the following:

```
all('a', text: 'Comprar')[0].click
```